# throws SecurityException when signing with the default debug keystore

Tags: android, android-securityexception

I am receiving a **SecurityException** since yesterday when I launch the service using signature protection level for permission with the default debug keystore. The strange thing is I wasn't receiving this error before yesterday and I didn't make any security related change.

On the other hand, my own keystore using for releases is still working good. Related **AndroidManifest.xml** part:

```
<permission android:name="com.my.app.privateservices"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<service android:name=".MyService"
    android:permission="com.my.app.privateservices" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I make my service unreachable by setting my signature as a permission requirement, I got this error randomly when using the debug signature. I don't know the reason. But I delete the permission setting of my service while developing when I got this error and insert it again before signing the application. But, as I said, generally I don't get this error.

I know that this is not the actual answer. But, it is a work around. Hope it helps someone else.

Thanks.