# Does protectionLevel "signature" work properly with Android debug keys?

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

I have a content provider and a test application both signed with a debug key. The client receives a content normally if permissions are not applied, but I want to apply permissions to the stuff. So the following lines are added into the content provider's manifest file:

```
  <permission android:name="org.example.provider.READ"
    android:permissionGroup="org.example.group.DATA_ACCESS"
    android:label="@string/readonlyaccess"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <application
    ...
    <provider android:name=".ImageContentProvider"
        android:authorities="org.example.provider"
        android:readPermission="org.example.provider.READ" />
```

In the client's manifest file the following line is added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="org.example.provider.READ" />
```

When I try to get the data from the provider, I get the error:

```
09-13 22:38:20.995: E/AndroidRuntime(13979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hello/com.example.hello.HelloActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading org.example.ImageContentProvider uri content://org.example.provider/file from pid=13979, uid=10040 requires org.example.provider.READ
```

Am I missing something, or is it related to the fact that the applications are signed by debug key? How to solve the problem? I saw a suggestion to add `uses-permission` to the provider as well, but this does not help either. NB. This is checked inside emulator, if this can be of any importance.

I found a related question [throws SecurityException when signing with the default debug keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420044/throws-securityexception-when-signing-with-the-default-debug-keystore), but it does not provide actual solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it works with debug keystores, at least the last time I tried it.

I would have the `<permission>` element in both apps. If you installed the `<uses-permission>` one first, and then installed the `<permission>` one, you would run into problems. The permission needs to be defined before the `<uses-permission>` is encountered, and the simplest way to do that is to put the `<permission>` in both.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "both" ? Because when I do that, I get a `INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION: Package com.foo attempting to redeclare permission com.bar.permission.GET_DATA already owned by com.bar`. Something might have changed in newer versions of Android.

Comment: @c4k: Both apps need to be signed by same signing key if they will be defining the same permission, on Android 5.0+.